# Creating 2D matrix from RDD

Tags: apache-spark, matrix, rdd

I have the following RDD of the Type ((UserID, MovieID),1):

```
val data_wo_header=dropheader(data).map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(0).toInt,x(1).toInt),1))
```

I want to convert this data structure into a 2D array such that all elements(userID Movie ID) present in the original RDD have a 1 else 0.

I think we have to map the user ID's to 0-N if N is the number of distinct users and map Movie ID's to 0-M if Mis the number of distinct movies.

EDIT: example

```
        Movie ID->

Userid  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

1       0 1 1 0 0 1 0 
2       0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
3       0 1 1 0 0 0 1 
4       1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
5       0 1 1 0 0 0 1 
6       1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
7       0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
8       0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
9       0 1 1 0 0 1 0 

The RDD will be of the sort
(userID, movID,rating)
101,1002,3.5
101,1003,2.5
101,1006,3
102,1002,3.5
102,1004,4.0
103,1002,1.0
103,1003,1.0
103,1007,5.0
….
```

Comment: can you share the expected output format ??

Comment: the output you can consider as a 2D matrix with 1 and 0 values for each user ID, Movie ID pair

Comment: can you give me a format. not able to visualize what you are exactly looking for

Comment: so you want to get a user with all the movies he has watched ? 
1       0 1 1 0 0 1 0  . something like this ?

Comment: Yes thats right, I dont know what kind of data structure should we use? 2D Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI I managed to generate the 2D matrix using the following function. It takes in the RDD of the format

```
((userID, movID),rating)
101,1002,3.5
101,1003,2.5
101,1006,3
102,1002,3.5
102,1004,4.0
103,1002,1.0
103,1003,1.0
103,1007,5.0
```

and returns the characteristic Matrix:

```
def generate_characteristic_matrix(data_wo_header:RDD[((Int, Int), Int)]):Array[Array[Int]]={
    val distinct_user_IDs=data_wo_header.sortByKey().map(x=>x._1._1).distinct().collect().sorted
    val distinct_movie_IDs=data_wo_header.sortByKey().map(x=>x._1._2).distinct().collect().sorted

    var movie_count=distinct_movie_IDs.size
    var user_count=distinct_user_IDs.size

    var a =0
    var map_movie = new ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)]()
    var map_user = new ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)]()
    //map movie ID's from (0,movie_count)
    for( a <- 0 to movie_count-1){
      map_movie+=((distinct_movie_IDs(a),a))
    }
    //map user ID's from (0,user_count)
    for( a <- 0 to user_count-1){
      map_user+=((distinct_user_IDs(a),a))
    }
    //size of char matrix is user_countxmovie_count
    var char_matrix = Array.ofDim[Int](user_count,movie_count)
    data_wo_header.collect().foreach(x => {
      var user =x._1._1
      var movie=x._1._2
      var movie_mappedid=map_movie.filter(x=>x._1==movie).map(x=>x._2).toArray
      var user_mappedid=map_user.filter(x=>x._1==user).map(x=>x._2).toArray
      char_matrix(user_mappedid(0))(movie_mappedid(0))=1
    })
    return char_matrix
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val baseRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq((101, 1002, 3.5), (101, 1003, 2.5), (101, 1006, 3), (102, 1002, 3.5), (102, 1004, 4.0), (103, 1002, 1.0), (103, 1003, 1.0), (103, 1007, 5.0)))    
      baseRDD.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).groupByKey().foreach(println)
```

(userID, movID,rating) format as you mentioned

**Result:**

(101,CompactBuffer(1002, 1003, 1006))

(102,CompactBuffer(1002, 1004))

(103,CompactBuffer(1002, 1003, 1007))

Comment: But how do we generate/print the 0 1 0 matrix?

Comment: you mean to say, you also want rating  given by the user ?  something like tis  (101(1002,4.0), (1003,3.5), (1006,4.0)) ??

Comment: I have  justmade the edit in the question. I want to print out the matrix in the format shown in the edit.The matrix has elements 0 1 1 0 0 1 0. the user id 101 is represented by row 1 of the matrix. Movie ID 1001 represented by column 1 of Matrix. Similarly Movie ID 1002 represented by column 2 and so on

Comment: Hi BDR, I just answered my question you may have a look.